# Twitter Bootstrap forms ugly inside Modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I just had a use case to view form inside modals with Bootstrap. But heck it looks different. I need to insert all form tags and loads of stuff just to make them look good. Could you guys suggest me what am i doing wrong? Also the textbox look weird ( small and size changed)

http://jsbin.com/welcome/53151/edit

Comment: This looks like intended behavior.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I don't get it, are they intended to be UGLY!!

Comment: I don't exactly see what is ugly. Maybe you should be using a `textarea` instead of an `input type="text"`, though.

Comment: @WaleedKhan checkout the textbox in the demos and the form inside modal( they have been shrunken and does not look nice)http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSBin CSS is interfering with the Bootstrap CSS.

This looks OK: http://jsbin.com/welcome/53151

On the full screen view, only code that you wrote and the libraries you selected are included. In the edit view, the JSBin.com styles apply to your HTML as well.

Comment: Ooh yeah the full screen seems to be perfect